# JavaFx + Felix on windows WinPlatformFactory not found

Tags: java, javafx, osgi, apache-felix

I have a desktop application that uses Apache felix and swing, with embebed  javafx UIs, javafx is being loaded into the project by a maven embebed dependency, and it works fine on mac.

But when i run it on windows it gives me the following error:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinPlatformFactory not found by my-software [38]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.findClassOrResourceByDelegation(BundleWiringImpl.java:1574)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.access$400(BundleWiringImpl.java:79)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl$BundleClassLoader.loadClass(undleWiringImpl.java:2018)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.PlatformFactory.getPlatformFactory(PlatformFactory.java:42)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.Application.run(Application.java:146)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.startup(QuantumToolkit.java:257)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:211)
    at javafx.embed.swing.JFXPanel.initFx(JFXPanel.java:215)
    at javafx.embed.swing.JFXPanel.<init>(JFXPanel.java:230)
    at br.com.mysoftware.fx.java.DownloadExplorer.initAndShowGUI(DownloadExplorer.java:68)
    at br.com.mysoftware.fx.java.DownloadExplorer$1.run(DownloadExplorer.java:120)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:756)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:726)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)____________________________Welcome to Apache Felix Gogo


    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)

    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82) Failed to load Glass factory class Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.glass.ui.Application.run(Application.java:146)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.startup(QuantumToolkit.java:257)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:211)
    at javafx.embed.swing.JFXPanel.initFx(JFXPanel.java:215)
    at javafx.embed.swing.JFXPanel.<init>(JFXPanel.java:230)
    at br.com.mysoftware.fx.java.DownloadExplorer.initAndShowGUI(DownloadExplorer.java:68)
    at br.com.mysoftware.fx.java.DownloadExplorer$1.run(DownloadExplorer.java:120)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:756)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:726)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)

    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> javafx is being loaded into the project by a maven embebed dependency

I don't think embedding the javafx jar is the correct approach, if that is what you're doing. You'll be missing some native parts, I guess.

Rather use the "org.osgi.framework.system.packages.extra" mechanism.

You can have a look at the Dromber FX code (the modular application framework for JavaFX, which combines JavaFX and OSGi ; I'm the author of this framework):

https://github.com/Drombler/drombler-fx/blob/release-0.9/drombler-fx-startup-main/src/main/resources/org/drombler/fx/startup/main/config.properties

Answer (score 0):

The error `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinPlatformFactory not found` may also occur if the Windows JavaFX version (e.g. from Gluon) was shared (clobbered with) the MacOS JavaFX version.

Seemingly safe, the MacOS JAR seems to be missing `WinPlatformFactory.class` component in the jar, causing the same error message as the OP.

```
⁨javafx.graphics⁩.jar!com⁩/sun/glass⁩/⁨ui⁩/⁨win⁩/WinPlatformFactory.class
```

The fix:

1. Do not use the same directory for all platforms
   --OR--
2. Clobber the MacOS version with the Windows version (**Warning:** could ultimate suffer an equal and opposite fate although testing does not seem to show this)