# Why does this .jar run in my ubuntu but not in windows?

Tags: java, maven, javafx, apache-poi, h2

I've been working on my first Java app these last few weeks. It uses JavaFX, Maven, Apache POI and H2 database. I have been having some problems to package it because of the Apache POI. After some searching I found a way to package it using this plugin:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.1</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>shade</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <finalName>fat-ultrasomma</finalName>
                <transformers>
                    <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                        <mainClass>ultrasomma.Main</mainClass>
                    </transformer>
                </transformers>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

and I was even able to make it run on Ubuntu using `java -jar fat-ultrasomma.jar`, but when I tried running on a Windows 10 that I already set JAVA_HOME and PATH to a java jdk 14 this error appears:

```
java -jar fat-ultrasomma.jar
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinPlatformFactory
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:602)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:340)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.PlatformFactory.getPlatformFactory(PlatformFactory.java:42)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.Application.run(Application.java:144)
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.startup(QuantumToolkit.java:280)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:269)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:158)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.startToolkit(LauncherImpl.java:658)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:678)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:195)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
Failed to load Glass factory class
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.sun.glass.ui.Application.run(Application.java:144)
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.startup(QuantumToolkit.java:280)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:269)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:158)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.startToolkit(LauncherImpl.java:658)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:678)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:195)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
```

I still don't understand why is this happening, and the goal of the project is to have it run on Windows.
Here is a link for to Github with the project: [github](https://github.com/VictorVirgolino/BalanceUSV4)

The `.jar` is in the target folder as `fat-ultrasomma.jar` if you want to try running it.

Please I really need to make it work.

Here is a print of the program working on ubuntu: [ubuntu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r2LCF.png)

Comment: Do you have the same JDK builds on both OS?

Comment: yes both open jdk 14

Comment: How are you including JavaFX though? If you're trying to bundle it as part of the jar, that simply won't work (it contains native graphics components, which are platform-dependent). The general strategy here is to build the jar file, then use [`jpackage`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/jpackage/) on each platform to generate a different bundle for the platform. (You could in theory just ship the jar, but you'd need to rely on users having javafx installed, and running it with options to point to the javafx modules.) Also see https://github.com/dlemmermann/JPackageScriptFX

Comment: i see i will try package it on windows

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaFx + Felix on windows WinPlatformFactory not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42418920/javafx-felix-on-windows-winplatformfactory-not-found)